# How to implement sign-in with Azure AD in a Blazor Hybrid application?

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, azure-authentication, blazor-hybrid

I have made a Blazor Hybrid application in .NET 6 and am looking to implement authentication and authorization with Azure AD. I found an [article by Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/hybrid/security/?view=aspnetcore-6.0&pivots=maui) on how to do it, but it says to

> Follow the guidance for the identity provider that you've selected for the app and then further integrate identity with Blazor using the guidance in this article.

and later in the article it says to

> Provide OpenID/MSAL code to authenticate the user. See your identity provider's
> documentation for details.

So the article already expects a part of the authentication to be implemented. To do that, I generally use the documentation in Azure Portal's Quickstart of a registered application. However, currently documentation is not present for a Blazor Hybrid app. I did some research of my own on how to implement it but I keep finding people doing it with Azure AD B2C, which I can't use. I only want sign-in with the regular Azure AD.

With an MVC project, I'd just add `services.AddAuthentication` with a few options. But I'm not sure what's the code for a Blazor Hybrid project.

How do I add authentication and authorization with Azure AD? In the Microsoft's tutorial, I am basically stuck at the step where it asks me for the code to authenticate the user.

Comment: Try this page : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio